# How do I remove the "Undo" option from Windows' right-click context menu?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, context-menu, right-click

I am looking to remove the `Undo` option from the menu.

I have looked at the similar questions on Super User, and I cannot find a method to remove this item. Please include more than just a link to some program in your answer.

[image: undo]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a hack  which might do what you ask for, but is somewhat risky.
I have not tested it, for obvious reasons, but it might work.

1. Download and install [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/)
2. Go to `C:\Windows\en-US` and take ownership of (if required) and then copy the explorer.exe.mui to somewhere safe.
   If you are running a 64-bit system you should also modify the explorer.exe.mui which is located in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\en-US`.
   To find all the copies: Go to Start Menu and do an extended search for explorer.exe.mui. You will need to repeat the procedure for each of them. If you have no success with saving the files you will also need to take ownership of the containing folder.
3. Open your explorer.exe.mui(s) in Resource Hacker and navigate to Menu / 205 / 1033 :
   [image]
4. Select and delete the Undo line
5. Press Compile Script and save
6. Go to your original folder(s) again and rename your original explorer.exe.mui file(s) (explorer0ld.exe.mui?) then copy and paste your modified explorer.exe.mui file(s) into place.
7. Go to Start Menu / Run and execute `mcbuilder`.
8. Once the window closes, restart your computer.

I take no responsibility for the result of the above or their effects. I suggest taking good backups first and creating a system restore point, just in case.

Comment: @Synetech: Actually, offsets in a hex-editor will be reliable. You simply look for `Undo` and then remove it properly. No need to change something based on an offset from the start of the file...

Comment: @Synetech: Nobody said it has to be simple, and using an index was your idea. First, Unicode doesn't matter if you do a proper search. Second, case is already proper, `Undo` as I said. Third, you are looking for a `MENUITEM`. Fourth, the surrounding bytes do not change between versions because resource files have been standardized. It's no rocket science and automating it is easy...

Comment: Calm down, guys. This is not a case of binary editing, rather the entire resources section is recompiled and replaced. Your argument has no meaning for the poster.

Comment: @Steven, you’ll need to re-patch it after running `sfc` or Windows Update.

Comment: yeah this will break explorer.exe's file integrity, i wouldn't recommend you doing this.

Comment: To clarify my position: This is the only answer to the post I can think of, but I wouldn't recommend doing that. However, FYI: many third-party "alternate themes" for Windows also install a replacement for Explorer and this works out fine, apparently because Explorer itself is rarely updated (rather the DLLs that it uses are updated).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to remove that previous actions like undo move/ undo
delete/ paste etc. But I can tell you how to prevent it from adding it
to the menu option.

Once you are done with moving/cutting/copying any file/folder and you
paste it to another location, the action is recorded but to remove it,
just move/cut/copy that file/folder in the current folder (where you
just moved your file recently) again, and a dialogue box appears, just
click skip and you will see, that annoying options are disappeared.

Comment: So if you want to move a file, you move it and then move it back to avoid seeing undo?  What about the primary objective?

Answer (score -1):

The best option is program called ShellToys. It's shareware (45 day free of try). With ShellToys you can (along with many other things) or hide remove many menu items. 
Note that this doesn't work with Windows 8 64-bit; it will work with other versions of Windows.

Comment: Link to the program?

Answer (score -2):

a solution that I use:
 1. right click and create a new folder
 2. press ctrl+c and copy it
 3. go inside the folder and press ctrl+v to paste
 4. it pops an error, skip on that
 5. go back and press F2 to rename the folder
 6. press ctrl+c to copy the string
 7. press esc and delete the folder
now there is no undo copy and pate item is disabled ( which is annoying if you accidentally click it instead of refresh!!!)